# Getting Exception connecting Yahoo server

Tags: java, swing

```
package session;

import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.text.DateFormat;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;
import org.openymsg.network.FireEvent;
import org.openymsg.network.Session;
import org.openymsg.network.SessionState;
import org.openymsg.network.event.SessionListener;

public class BotGUI extends javax.swing.JFrame implements SessionListener{

    /** Creates new form BotGUI */
    FileWriter fw;
    DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy/MM/dd HH:mm:ss");
    public BotGUI() {
        initComponents();
    }
    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">
    private void initComponents() {

        jPanel1 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel2 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jPanel3 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jPanel4 = new javax.swing.JPanel();
        jLabel2 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        jLabel3 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
        uNameTextField = new javax.swing.JTextField();
        uPassPasswordField = new javax.swing.JPasswordField();
        jButton1 = new javax.swing.JButton();
        jMenuBar1 = new javax.swing.JMenuBar();
        jMenu1 = new javax.swing.JMenu();
        jMenuItem1 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem2 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenuItem3 = new javax.swing.JMenuItem();
        jMenu2 = new javax.swing.JMenu();

        setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        jPanel2.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jPanel3.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(51, 51, 51));

        jLabel1.setBackground(new java.awt.Color(0, 0, 255));
        jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 12));
        jLabel1.setForeground(new java.awt.Color(255, 255, 255));
        jLabel1.setText("Yahoo Login Panel");

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel3Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel3);
        jPanel3.setLayout(jPanel3Layout);
        jPanel3Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel3Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addGap(38, 38, 38)
                .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 140, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(532, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );
        jPanel3Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel3Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jLabel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.TRAILING, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, 30, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        jPanel2.add(jPanel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 0, 710, 30));

        jPanel4.setLayout(new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteLayout());

        jLabel2.setText("Username");
        jPanel4.add(jLabel2, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(30, 20, 60, 20));

        jLabel3.setText("Password");
        jPanel4.add(jLabel3, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(270, 20, 60, 20));
        jPanel4.add(uNameTextField, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(100, 20, 140, 20));
        jPanel4.add(uPassPasswordField, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(330, 20, 140, -1));

        jButton1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
        jButton1.setText("Login");
        jButton1.addActionListener(new java.awt.event.ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
                jButton1ActionPerformed(evt);
            }
        });
        jPanel4.add(jButton1, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(490, 15, 90, -1));

        jPanel2.add(jPanel4, new org.netbeans.lib.awtextra.AbsoluteConstraints(0, 30, 710, 60));

        javax.swing.GroupLayout jPanel1Layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(jPanel1);
        jPanel1.setLayout(jPanel1Layout);
        jPanel1Layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        jPanel1Layout.setVerticalGroup(
            jPanel1Layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addGroup(jPanel1Layout.createSequentialGroup()
                .addComponent(jPanel2, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 135, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
                .addContainerGap(293, Short.MAX_VALUE))
        );

        jMenu1.setText("Option");

        jMenuItem1.setText("Logout");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem1);

        jMenuItem2.setText("Load CSV");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem2);

        jMenuItem3.setText("Exit");
        jMenu1.add(jMenuItem3);

        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu1);

        jMenu2.setText("Help");
        jMenuBar1.add(jMenu2);

        setJMenuBar(jMenuBar1);

        javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
        getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
        layout.setHorizontalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );
        layout.setVerticalGroup(
            layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
            .addComponent(jPanel1, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, javax.swing.GroupLayout.DEFAULT_SIZE, Short.MAX_VALUE)
        );

        pack();
    }// </editor-fold>

    public void handleConnectionClosed() {
        connectionClosed = true;
        loggedIn = false;
    }

    private void jButton1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
        if(!uNameTextField.getText().equals("") && !uPassPasswordField.getText().equals("")){
            Yahoo_login(uNameTextField.getText(),uPassPasswordField.getText());
        }else{
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Plese Enter User Id and Password");
        }
    }

   Session yahooMessengerSession;
    MySessionListener mySessionListener;
    boolean loggedIn = false;
    boolean connectionClosed = false;

    public void Yahoo_login(String uName, String pass) {
        connectionClosed = false;
        if (loggedIn == false) {
            yahooMessengerSession = new Session();
            mySessionListener = new MySessionListener(this);
            yahooMessengerSession.addSessionListener(mySessionListener);

            try {
                if ((uName.equals("")) || (pass.equals("")))
                    {
                        System.out.println("User name/password is blank");
                    }
                else{
                        //initialized a file writer for log file
                        System.out.println("Login start........");
                        yahooMessengerSession.login(uName, pass, true);
                        //checks whether user was succesful in login in
                        if (yahooMessengerSession!=null && yahooMessengerSession.getSessionStatus()== SessionState.LOGGED_ON) {
                            //this loop is reached when the user has been successfully logined
                            System.out.println("Login Success");
                            fw.write("User (" + uName + ") logged in at : " + dateFormat.format("09.05.10") + " \n");
                            fw.close();
               } else {
                   yahooMessengerSession.reset();
              }
           }
         } catch(Exception e){ }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                new BotGUI().setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    // Variables declaration - do not modify
    private javax.swing.JButton jButton1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel2;
    private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel3;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu1;
    private javax.swing.JMenu jMenu2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuBar jMenuBar1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem1;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem2;
    private javax.swing.JMenuItem jMenuItem3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel1;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel2;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel3;
    private javax.swing.JPanel jPanel4;
    private javax.swing.JTextField uNameTextField;
    private javax.swing.JPasswordField uPassPasswordField;
    // End of variables declaration

    public void dispatch(FireEvent fe) {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
    }

}
```

===========================================================================================

## i have to find the error

SEVERE: error during the dispatch of event: FireEvent [org.openymsg.network.event.SessionListEvent to:null from:null message:null timestamp:0 status:0 list type:Friends size:2 LIST]
java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: Not supported yet.
        at yahoomessangerbot.MySessionListener.dispatch(MySessionListener.java:131)
        at org.openymsg.network.EventDispatcher.runEventNOW(EventDispatcher.java:133)
        at org.openymsg.network.EventDispatcher.run(EventDispatcher.java:114)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://jymsg9.sourceforge.net/docs/ymsg/network/Session.html

This will help u..